# Using a general purpose selector as a mixin in LESS CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, less

I know about mixins and parametric mixins. What we are looking for is a way to make any general purpose selectors in CSS / LESS into a mixin.

Eg in [Twitter BootStrap](https://github.com/rcorp/bootstrap), we have [here](https://github.com/rcorp/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L233)

```
.navbar .nav > li {
  float: left;
}
```

If I have to use it in a class say .mynavbar I want to be able to do this

```
INPUT->
.mynavbar {
  .navbar .nav >li;
}
```

---

```
OUTPUT->
.mynavbar {
  float:left;
}
```

Now I know this can't be done with the current version of LESS as the compiler flags a parser error. I wanted someone to help me out on changing the source code of less.js a little so that this is workable.

I've managed to reach [the source code for the mixin parser](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L825). I've tried changing the RegExp there, but it interferes with other parts of the parser. I know we have to make only a few changes because, instead of just accepting `.mixin` and `#mixin` we have to accept any mixin like tags / attribute selectors like `input[type=text]`.

It is currently needed for the development of a UI framework that uses Bootstrap. Unfortunately many places in bootstrap are littered with direct tag selectors instead of ids and classes.

Comment: Why do you want this?  Why not just make a mixin for the styles you want, and include the mixin where you need it?  For example... take the places in Twitter Bootstrap that have direct tag selectors, copy the code inside of them, and create a new class for that code.  Then apply the mixin to the direct tag selector.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Yeah. Thats what we do for in-house LESS Code, but for Bootstrap that has a really fast release cycle, each time they release a new version of the code, we'd have to change our class mixins by keeping on copying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would strongly discourage doing such things. Instead, try to use the power of CSS and build your HTML such that the bootstrap rules apply, for example. Anyway, since you asked for it, here is the solution.

The problem is not the complexity of the selector, or the child rule, but the tag name selector part (i. e. the `li`). So, what we have to fix is the mixin parser only matching classes and ids. I guess we would not want to tamper with [the first class or id test](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L821), <s>since that is probably needed to distinguish mixins from normal CSS rules (although the tests run fine with that check commented out).</s> (Actually, there is a parser preference in action, and the only thing tried after mixins are comments and directives, so we can safely remove that check as well). However, we can easily allow tag names in later parts of the mixin selector by adding a question mark after `[#.]` in the matching regular expression. So

```
while (e = $(/^[#.](?:[\w-]|\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9]))+/)) {
```

– i. e. [line 825](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L825) – becomes

```
while (e = $(/^[#.]?(?:[\w-]|\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9]))+/)) {
```

The test cases still run through fine, afterwards, but subtle breakage my occur, so be cautious.

**Edit:** There is a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/1011) for the same problem. Apparently the less folks rather want the mixin feature to be more narrow and function-like, instead of allowing a more flexible … well … mixing in of rules. With regard to the CSS output, that's probably reasonable.

Comment: I would agree with you completely. For our "native" websites we do modify the HTML so that it syncs with bootstrap. Actually we are wanting to integrate Bootstrap to a JavaScript Framework and its brand of CSS. The HTML Tags are out of our control.

That being said, don't you think its bad practice to directly style tag selectors in any case?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer! Could you please explain the RegExp in detail if possible? Which edge cases do you think it would fail for? 
I didn't quite understand "the first class or id test". Its a valid point. Will the Tag Selector act as a mixin or will it be the Computed output of all styles of that selector.

We are yet to test it completely. Will give you feedback asap.

Comment: Ok, so I took another look at the parser. There is an [explicit order](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L522) in which things are tried to parse, and right now mixin calls are only tried before comments and directives, so these are the only things an over-zealous mixin call parser might accept falsely. Since both are strictly parsed, we might move the mixin call parse down in the prio list. I've pushed a [more robust version](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/commit/70241ef1846952faa25891349bf87b1613abb03d), btw.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible [since version 1.4.0 (2013-06-05)](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta-1--2) of LESS that include the `extend` feature. Based on the original example

```
.navbar .nav > li {
  float: left;
}

.mynavbar:extend(.navbar .nav > li) {}
```

compiles to

```
.navbar .nav > li,
.mynavbar {
  float: left;
}
```

Documentation [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) and discussion & example use for the original question [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1048)

**EDIT:** Added Code Sample

Comment: Your previous answer was deleted because it's little more than a link. If there's example code in the link, you should add it here.