# Less nested class with html tag

Tags: css, less

How can I do that (nested class with html tag) in Angular2 application:

```
/***** File2.less *****/
@import "File1.less";
O-hr:nth-child(odd) {
    O-hr.color1;              //Error
}

/***** File1.less *****/
O-hr.color1 {
    .caption {
        color: @highlight1-backcolor;
    }
}
```

Compiler gives me error: Module build failed: Unrecognised input.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a dot `.` like that, since it is a special character in CSS, which one use for classes, try a dash `O-hr-color1`

Comment: Hi, same error. I am not sure if it possible. I just wonder.

Comment: Don't know LESS that good so can't say more

Comment: Duplicate of [Using a general purpose selector as a mixin in LESS CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533957/using-a-general-purpose-selector-as-a-mixin-in-less-css)